# how to upload file in Strong-Type view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I use:

`@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadPackage", "Manager"))`

to send webForm data to `UploadPackage` action.

**Now** I add an input tag whose type is file(`< input type = "file" />`) in that strong-type view.  **What I want to do is**: How can I get all data from webForm (including file) in my Action and handle them?

Comment: any help will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form in view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 
     @Html.ValidationSummary();
     <ol>
     <li class="lifile">
     <input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="file" />
     <span class="field-validation-error" id="spanfile"></span>
     </li>
     </ol>
     <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Upload" />
}
```

At Controllers side :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
     // Implementation
}
```