# File uploading in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a form it's creating by script in jquery plugin like this.

```
elem.insertHtml('<form method="post" action="Home/ContactUs" enctype="mutlipart/form-data"><input type="file" name="file" id="fileUpload"></form></div>')
```

I must upload a file, and save it in some folder. When I choose a file, and submit form, on  form subbmiting calling the ContactUs action.There is ContactUs action from Home controller.

```
public ActionResult ContactUs(HttpPostedFileBase file, ContactFormModel model)
{
    //other code
}
```

But HttpPostedFileBase file is null, and  I havn't got any notions why. Can you help me, please?

When I create my form usin Html.BeginForm, it works correctly, by but script there is a problem.

Comment: Can it be because of the typo in `enctype="mutlipart/form-data"`?

Comment: Check my approved answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440220/how-to-upload-file-in-strong-type-view-in-asp-net-mvc/18441187#18441187

Comment: Without enctype I will have a validation error.

Comment: I think you're missing @Anton's point - you've put `mutlipart/form-data` instead of `multipart/form-data`

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'File' method for uploading file and retrieve them. create a folder in your project something likes 'FileUploads' and then upload File in there. I give you a link where you can see full implementation :-
[Upload,Save and Retrieve Image from database by using their Id in Code First Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23517615/upload-save-and-retrieve-image-from-database-by-using-their-id-in-code-first-met/23544539#23544539)

Answer (score 1):

Create HTML form from like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="text" name="Subject"/>
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Also make sure in your Controller, the Method has an attribute `[HttpPost]` like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ContactUs(HttpPostedFileBase file, ContactFormModel model)
{
    //other code
}
```

Comment: But my form created by script. And I can't create it in .cshtml view file.

Comment: Do you have the `HttpPost` attribute? Updated my answer. @dotNet_d19

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your model binding is not working in your code. It is your view strongly typed?

Try it whith this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8551621/2664142

Answer (score 0):

Could you change from

```
elem.insertHtml('<form method="post" action="Home/ContactUs" enctype="mutlipart/form-data"><input type="file" name="file" id="fileUpload"></form></div>')
```

To

```
elem.insertHtml('<form method="post" action="Home/ContactUs" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" name="file" id="fileUpload"></form></div>')
```

Could you check Request.Files.Count it must be more than 0 if not could you comment me please

```
 public ActionResult ContactUs(ContactFormModel model)
 {
    Request.Files[0].SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"~\files\test.jpg"));
    return View();
 }
```