# HttpPostedFileBase is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have controller like this :

```
public ActionResult SaveBook(Book coll, HttpPostedFileBase EBook)
{
}
```

and view like the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveBook", "Book", FormMethod.Post,
            new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Book</legend>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ISBN)</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ISBN)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ISBN)</td>
            </tr>
 <tr><td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EBook) </td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EBook, new { type = "file", accept = ".pdf" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EBook)</td></tr>
        </table>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="SaveBook" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

My Model like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Title Required")]
public  String  Title { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "ISBN Required")]
public  String  ISBN { get; set; }
public HttpPostedFileBase EBook { get; set; }
```

But still I am getting value fro EBook "null" value in "EBook" object or in the "coll" object  of the Controller. Any suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440220/how-to-upload-file-in-strong-type-view-in-asp-net-mvc/18441187#18441187

Comment: In your Action, can you see the file in `Request.Files`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have same name in your model, you are getting it null. happened to me yesterday as well rename one of them to something else.

Try following:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="file" name="file" />
    </div>
```

Similarlar you action should be

```
public ActionResult SaveBook(Book coll, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
}
```

Comment: Already tried, actually at first hand I tried that only, after that keep on trying with others

Answer (score 0):

EBook is already a property of your Model. Change your Action to the following for the model binding to work properly:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveBook(Book coll)
{ 
}
```

Comment: Also, make sure you use the `HttpPost` attribute like in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The fact I found now. I increase maxRequestLength like:

```
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
```

and it worked.