# How to send file to webservice through javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

can i send file through java script to web Service in asp.net? If yes, how to send that file? Need to Convert the file into byte array...?
this my code  send file through javascript?please see my code below

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UploadData.aspx.cs" Inherits="FileUploadWebService.UploadData" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            Id:  
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />

            File:
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /><br />
                   <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="Server"/>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="Button1_Click" />



        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

this is my script.i got bytes in alert but webservice is not calling....in browser only  got exception

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = document.getElementById("txtId").value;
    var byteArrays = [];
    function getFile() {
        debugger;


        var data = document.getElementById("FileUpload1");
        // var file = $("#objFile")[0].files[0];
        var file = data.files[0];
        fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = receivedText;
        //fr.readAsText(file);
        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    function receivedText() {
        var b64Data = fr.result.split(',');
        var contentType = 'image/jpeg';
        //document.getElementById('editor').appendChild(document.createTextNode(fr.result))
        var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data[1]);
        var byteNumbers = Array.prototype.map.call(byteCharacters,
                                       charCodeFromCharacter);
        var uint8Data = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        var blob = b64toBlob(b64Data[1], contentType);
        //var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    }

    function charCodeFromCharacter(c) {
        return c.charCodeAt(0);
    }

    function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
        contentType = contentType || '';
        sliceSize = sliceSize || 1024;
        var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);


        for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
            var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
            var byteNumbers = Array.prototype.map.call(slice, charCodeFromCharacter);
            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
            byteArrays.push(byteArray);
            for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
                alert(byteArray[i]);
            }

        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:51963/FileUploadService.asmx/ServiceForFileUpLoad",
            data: { ID: id, Data: file },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert(x.responseText + "  " + x.status);
            }
        });
    }


</script>
</html>
```

this is my service code

```
[webmethod]
     public string UploadDataService(int id, byte[] bytes)
            {
                return "sucess";
            }
```

Comment: There are numerous examples on StackOverflow. Have you tried a Google search or even searching StackOverflow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to send uploaded file from javascript to controller in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996968/how-to-send-uploaded-file-from-javascript-to-controller-in-mvc)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have tried.I converted file into bytes .while sending bytes to webservice getting timedout exception.

Comment: Can we see your 'FileUploadService.asmx/ServiceForFileUpLoad' file? does it even exist?

Comment: yaa sure.just i returned simple sucess for checking webservice is calling or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you read a file as dataURL and then recreate the file but as a blob... pointless

- Use multipart form upload when uploading files included with custom fields
- Don't read it as dataURL and send everything as a json object. the file will be ~3x larger for upload and it also takes time to compile/decompile
- Sending a form data with jQuery is never easy ([see how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery)), that is why i prefer the new fetch api, that + it's promisifyed so you can use async/await

```js
window.upload = async function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault()
  
  let form1 = document.getElementById('form1')
  let body = new FormData(form1)
  let opts = {
    method: 'post',
    body
  }
  
  let res = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', opts)
  let json = await res.json()
  console.log(json)
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <input name="id" value="2">
  <input name="txt" type="file">
  <input type="submit" onclick="upload(event)">
</form>
```